# Different big O notation for same calculation(Cracking the coding interview)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

In Cracking the Coding Interview, 6th edition, page 6, the amortized time for insertion is explained as:

> As we insert elements, we double the capacity when the size of the array is a power of 2.  So after X elements, we double the capacity at
> array sizes 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... , X.
>
> That doubling takes, respectively, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ... , X
> copies. What is the sum of 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + X?
>
> If you read this sum left to right, it starts with 1 and doubles until
> it gets to X. If you read right to left, it starts with X and halves
> until it gets to 1.
>
> What then is the sum of X + X/2 + X/4 + ... + 1? This is roughly 2X.
> Therefore, X insertions take O( 2X) time. The amortized time for each
> insertion is O(1).

While for this code snippet(a recursive algorithm),
`

```
int f(int n) { 

  if (n <= 1) {
  return 1;
  }

 return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1); `
```

The explanation is:

> The tree will have depth N. Each node has two children. Therefore,
> each level will have twice as many calls as the one above it.
> Therefore,there will be 2^0+ 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^N(which is
> 2^(N+1) - 1) nodes. . In this case, this gives us O(2^N) .

My question is:
In the first case, we have a GP 1+2+4+8...X. In the 2nd case we have the same GP 1+2+4+8..2^N. Why is the sum 2X in one case while it is 2^(N+1)-1 in another.

I think that it might be because we can't represent X as 2^N but I'm not sure.

Comment: if you consider 2^N as X, you get the same thing.  2*X = 2 * (2^N) = 2^(N+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the second case N is the depth of the tree and not the total number of nodes. It would be 2^N = X, as you already stated.